# how to cache posts in javascript then fetch only the new ones?

Tags: javascript, caching, local-storage

i've made a site that let people write posts like facebook,etc...
but i came to a problem of fetching those posts everytime the client requests it from the database over and over again 
so i needed to cache the previous posts and fetch only the new ones from the DB
lets say i have posts 1,2,3,4,5 that are cached and the server has posts 1,2,3,4,5,6
how can i fetch only post 6?
i mean how can i tell the server that i have 1...5 posts?
give me a headway of caching posts techniques please
i'll be gratefull
thanks in advance

Comment: please add your code

Comment: It really depends what backend you are using, but generally you can give an offset in your request. But without your JavaScript in the frontend (part which makes the request) and the code of your server side (which receives the request and makes the DB request) it is hard to tell. Please add your code so we can take a look.

Comment: i'm using ASP Web api with entity framework as my backend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume that posts have unique increment id, then you can store last used id, and each time request all posts with id greater than you have.

Comment: thanks for the idea but what if post 3 for example got deleted and the last used id is 5?

Comment: than you must have list with deleted id's: [delete_id, post_id] in the same way.

Comment: so the server has two jobs: the first is to fetch me the posts which their ids are higher and the second is to check deleted ids and response them to client too right?

Comment: Almost correct. Server must **collect** deleted id's, and if possible store it in database. On first call you get: list of posts, last-post-id, last-delete-id. Whenever you check for new data, fetch: posts from last-post-id, deletes from last-delete-id, last-post-id, last-delete-id.